# How to configure MyPy for Polars API Extension?

Tags: python, mypy, python-polars

I'm writing data manipulation code around `polars` Series and DataFrames.
To make my life easier and the code more readable, I use the [Polars API extensions](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api.html):

```py
@pl.api.register_dataframe_namespace("split")
class SplitFrame:
    def __init__(self, df: pl.DataFrame):
        self._df = df

    def by_alternate_rows(self) -> list[pl.DataFrame]:
        df = self._df.with_row_count(name="n")
        return [
            df.filter((pl.col("n") % 2) == 0).drop("n"),
            df.filter((pl.col("n") % 2) != 0).drop("n"),
        ]


pl.DataFrame(
    data=["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff"],
    columns=[("txt", pl.Utf8)],
).split.by_alternate_rows()

# [┌─────┐  ┌─────┐
#  │ txt │  │ txt │
#  │ --- │  │ --- │
#  │ str │  │ str │
#  ╞═════╡  ╞═════╡
#  │ aaa │  │ bbb │
#  │ ccc │  │ ddd │
#  │ eee │  │ fff │
#  └─────┘, └─────┘]
```

My problem is that my codebase is checked by MyPy, which doesn't like them one bit:

```bash
error: "DataFrame" has no attribute "split"  [attr-defined]
```

At the moment I can think of two workarounds, none of which is satisfying:

1. `# type: ignore` comments
   It is what I'm doing at the moment, but they need to be everywhere and ruin a little bit the codebase.
2. Stub files
   I didn't explore this avenue but I know one can provide stubfiles for a library. My issue here is that both Polars and my extensions are actively developed so I don't want to "freeze" their signatures, as I think maintaining these stubs will be a real burden.

Essentially I would like to tell MyPy *"Please assume polars.DataFrame has a `split` attribute of type `SplitFrame`."*
That's it.
Any suggestions on how to do this or something serving the same purpose would be appreciated.

Comment: Not related to your actual question but polars can do that split with [`.unstack()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.unstack.html#polars.DataFrame.unstack) if you're  not already aware: `df.unstack(2, how="horizontal")`

Comment: Thanks but the example above is from the Polars website, not my actual use-case.

Comment: another option could be using the `pipe` function: https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.pipe.html#polars.DataFrame.pipe

Answer (score 4):

Stub files are usually the way to go here, though they can be a bit of a pain to keep up-to-date. We have a significant piece of dynamically-generated syntax in our codebase at work and solved it by having a pre-commit hook that uses `mypy` stubgen. First it generates the usual static typing, but then we import/introspect the runtime version of the relevant class and inject the dynamically-registered methods into the stub. It does take a bit of work to do this, but once done you never have to touch it again, so the effort can definitely pay off if you're actively developing/extending the code.

This would be an example of generating standard stubs for a module; you could then read that file and inject dynamically-assigned methods into it.

```py
from mypy.stubgen import Options as StubOptions, generate_stubs

module_file = os.path.abspath( module_path )
module_stubfile = f"{module_file}i"

# create the standard _static_ typing stub
generate_stubs(
    StubOptions(
        # 'module_file' contains the base class 
        #  onto which dynamic methods are registered
        files = [module_file],
        include_private = True,
        export_less = False,

        # standard params (not auto-defaulted)
        pyversion = sys.version_info[:2],
        interpreter = sys.executable,
        output_dir = '',
        ignore_errors = False,
        parse_only = True,
        no_import = True,
        search_path = [],
        doc_dir = '',
        packages = [],
        modules = [],
        verbose = False,
        quiet = False,
    )
)
```

It may also be worth investigating `mypy` plugin hooks, though I honestly can't speak to their effectiveness in this scenario: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extending_mypy.html

Answer (score 3):

A workaround would be to ignore the `attr-defined` error code globally. You can do this by adding the following to your `pyproject.toml`:

```ini
[tool.mypy]
disable_error_code = ["attr-defined"]
```

Another option is to disable type checking for the Polars library completely:

```ini
[[tool.mypy.overrides]]
module = "polars"
follow_imports = "skip"
```

Neither of these options feel good, but they would suppress the false positives you're seeing.